# splashScreen - fading in but ideally not out till the end

Tags: jquery

I'm using a bit of code to create a sort of splash screen fading in and out a few images using the files on here:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/apple-style-splash-screen-jquery/

however i'm trying to work out how to stop the images from fading out so it then creates an image slowly building up before finally fading out to reveal the website underneath...

I'm very new at this so trying to find the code to change is proving an issue for me
I'm using the code below - any chance anyone can guide me to what i need to change to achieve the result i'm after ?

// A self-executing anonymous function,
// standard technique for developing jQuery plugins.

(function($){

```
$.fn.splashScreen = function(settings){

    // Providing default options:

    settings = $.extend({
        textLayers      : [],
        textShowTime    : 3500,
        textTopOffset   : 80
    },settings);

    var promoIMG = this;

    // Creating the splashScreen div.
    // The rest of the styling is in splashscreen.css

    var splashScreen = $('<div>',{
        id  : 'splashScreen',
        css:{
            backgroundImage     : promoIMG.css('backgroundImage'),
            backgroundPosition  : 'center '+promoIMG.offset().top+'px',
            height              : $(document).height()
        }
    });

    $('body').append(splashScreen);

    splashScreen.click(function(){
        splashScreen.fadeOut('slow');
    });

    // Binding a custom event for changing the current visible text according 
    // to the contents of the textLayers array (passed as a parameter)

    splashScreen.bind('changeText',function(e,newID){

        // If the image that we want to show is
        // within the boundaries of the array:

        if(settings.textLayers[newID]){
            showText(newID);
        }
        else {
            splashScreen.click();
        }
    }); 

    splashScreen.trigger('changeText',0);

    // Extracting the functionality as a 
    // separate function for convenience.

    function showText(id){
        var text = $('<img>',{
            src:settings.textLayers[id],
            css: {
                marginTop : promoIMG.offset().top+settings.textTopOffset
            }
        }).hide();

        text.load(function(){
            text.fadeIn('slow').delay(settings.textShowTime).fadeOut('slow',function(){text.remove();
                splashScreen.trigger('changeText',[id+1]);
            });
        });

        splashScreen.append(text);
    }

    return this;
}
```

})(jQuery);